# Why is the app crashed when I try to use Timer to launch nativeCanvas.drawText periodically with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I hope to call nativeCanvas.drawText periodically to draw a text with Jetpack Compose.

But I get Result A when I run Code A.

1: What's wrong with my code?

2: How can I nativeCanvas.drawText a text  periodically ?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun ScreenHome_Watch(

){
    Box(        
    ) {        
        Canvas(             
        ) {    
            startTimer{
                drawIntoCanvas {
                    it.nativeCanvas.drawText("Hello "+Calendar.getInstance().time.toString() ,10f,10f, paintText)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private lateinit var timer: Timer

fun startTimer(block: ()->Unit) {
    timer = Timer()
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask {
        block()
    }, 0, 1000)
}
```

**Result A**

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.EmptyCanvas cannot be cast to androidx.compose.ui.graphics.AndroidCanvas
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to break the mechanism of the composition. You must change the state and compose will process the changes

```
@Composable
fun ScreenHome_Watch() {
    var currentTime by remember { mutableStateOf(Calendar.getInstance().time) }
    val paint = remember {
        Paint().apply {
            isAntiAlias = true
            textSize = 24f
            typeface = Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD)
        }
    }

    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.size(height = 20.dp, width = 180.dp)) {
        drawIntoCanvas {
            it.nativeCanvas.drawText(
                "Hello $currentTime", 30f, 30f, paint
            )
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        while (true) {
            currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().time
            delay(1000)
        }
    }
}
```